# Unity (NGUI) how to scale object in scroll view

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, scrollview, ngui

Using NGUI I created a horizontal scrollview with NGUI's example code "UICenter on Child". This is working properly. I want to dynamically scale the center sprite to 120%. How can I accomplish this? I am new to Unity so please provide a complete syntax -- something I can copy and paste into my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try default option:

```
Transform mainTransform;

void Start()
{
    mainTransform = transform;

    mainTransform.localScale = Vector3.one * 1.2f;
}
```